# Compile Multiple Files Into One Executable In Visual Studio Compiler - C++

Tags: c++, cl

just a simple question I want to compile multiple files into one executable using the visual studio compiler (or as I call it "cl.exe").

for instance I have "main.cpp" this file needs a header file called "file.h" I need to compile both these files into one executable. I think you can do that in g++ so is there a way to do it in vs compiler?

oh by the way I'm not developing inside visual studio I'm just using the build tools.

thanks.

Comment: You don't compile headers directly so in this case you have 1 file to build `main.cpp`

Comment: sorry I didn't make myself more clear the header belongs to a third party library from github, don't i need to compile the c++ and header files of that library too? sorry again I'm new to c++

Comment: ***don't i need to compile the c++ and header files of that library too?*** You probably have to read the instructions on how to build that. Some libraries will provide binary downloads. Others will require you to install a utility like CMake which you can use to generate a Makefile and use nmake via the command line and others will require you to install the Visual Studio Community IDE. For a person new to c++ this is likely going to be difficult to do via just using the command line msvc compiler. I don't consider this a beginner task.

Comment: you're right, there is a makefile. thanks